# Return the date when sum of negative values convert list of positive number into negative

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, sum

I am currently facing a challenge in Microsoft Excel and would greatly appreciate your assistance. Any advice or guidance you can provide would be of immense help to me.

My issue pertains to a table I have created to track debts and payments made by our customers. In the attached image, I have visualized how the table is structured. I need to find the oldest debt date that the customer has not paid yet. In the table below, customer A has paid total of 800 CU, and it covers debt till 05.11.2022. The formula I want should return that date.

| Customer Name | Date | Debt(+)/Payment(-) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01.10.2022 | 500 |
| A | 05.11.2022 | 400 |
| A | 10.12.2022 | -300 |
| B | 14.01.2023 | 100 |
| C | 18.02.2023 | 800 |
| A | 25.03.2023 | -400 |
| A | 29.04.2023 | -100 |
| A | 03.06.2023 | 150 |
| D | 08.07.2023 | -250 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=XLOOKUP(800,SCAN(0,FILTER(C2:C10,A2:A10="A"),LAMBDA(x,y,x+y)),FILTER(B2:B10,A2:A10="A"),,1)
```

This would also return the same date for an amount of 900. Not sure if that's what you are after. Best to cross-check multiple options and see if it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

my idea to solve it is add a helper column then use it to calculate the minimum date
[image]

the equation in helper column is the sum of all negative values for each customer and addition to the sum of the positive values for each customer from first row tile the currant row

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$10,$A$2:$A$10,A2,$C$2:$C$10,"<0")+SUMIFS($C$2:C2,$A$2:A2,A2,$C$2:C2,">0")
```

the equation of Minimum date

```
=MINIFS($B$2:$B$10,$A$2:$A$10,A2,$D$2:$D$10,">0")
```

Edit:
better to calculate the date out of that table with the same equation as to prevent any miss calculations in sorting data like :

```
=MINIFS($B$2:$B$10,$A$2:$A$10,F3,$D$2:$D$10,">0")
```

[image]

Comment: Aly Abdelaal. Thank you so much. It is working. But I am curious it shows different results when I sort dates in oldest to newest format or vice versa. Is there any way to correct it?

Comment: Mirzakarimboy Akhmadjonov   just be sure to sorting all of data not the date only and separate the date calculation out of the table of sorting like the edited answer